# Wildcard stopped working

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

Suddenly `*` just stopped working and simple program:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.txt
do
    echo $f
done
```

just produce `*.txt` string instead of files in the directory (or nothing). But `*` without any additional characters works fine. What's wrong? It's just ridiculous because it worked yesterday.

Bash version is 4.4.12(1)-release.

Comment: Possibly there is an invisible character like a CR (aka `\r`) one after `*.txt` in there. See the output of `sed -n l < your-script`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it placed $ instead of line feed. The same script works on virtual machine.

Comment: You'll have to `shopt -s nullglob` to have Bash expand the glob to nothing when it doesn't match. By default it leaves unmatched globs as-is. Did you do any changes to the script or the shell's environment since yesterday? Or anything else? I find it hard to believe your shell would change behaviour just like that just based on a day passing.

Comment: What about GLOBIGNORE? Is it set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either simple do not have any files in the current directory that have `.txt` as their file name suffix, or there's an invisible character at the end of the line in the script, such as a carriage return.

A carriage return may have snuck in there if you edited the script text file on a Windows machine and saved it as a DOS text file.

To remove these from all lines, use `dos2unix` on the script file.

In either case, the pattern does not expand because there's nothing matching it.  The shell therefore keeps the unexpanded pattern.

If you want the script to skip the loop completely if there are no matching filenames, then set the `nullglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

This makes `bash` expand non-matching patterns to the empty string.

Comment: No. I'm not using DOS or Windows. And I this also doesn't work in the shell but does on virtual machine.

Comment: @ДмитрийТерехов In that case, it's because there are no `.txt` files in the current directory.

Comment: No. There are .txt files. If there is none it should produce "*.txt" string. It should display nothing.

Comment: @ДмитрийТерехов You may in that case be looking at the wrong directory? I've added to the answer how to make it print nothing if there are no matches.

Comment: That behaviour is just ridiculous. If nothing matched - let's print just a string.

Comment: @ДмитрийТерехов I'm sorry, what? You just said "it should display nothing.", which it does when `nullglob` is in effect.

Comment: @ДмитрийТерехов, see [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, thanks for that ref. That's a good writeup.